# Skype bot attachment download in bot builder v4

Tags: botframework, skype

I'm trying to download an image uploaded in Skype bot using Bot Builder v4. I've retrieved the JwtSecurityToken for Authorization when using httpClient to download the image. But sometimes I'm receiving unauthorized error.

```
var context = stepContext.Context;
var channelId = context.Activity.ChannelId;

if (channelId.Equals("skype"))
{
    using (var connectorClient = (ConnectorClient)context.TurnState.First(x => x.Key.Equals("Microsoft.Bot.Connector.IConnectorClient")).Value)
    {
        if (connectorClient?.Credentials != null)
        {
           var credentials = (MicrosoftAppCredentials)connectorClient.Credentials;
           var authToken = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials(credentials.MicrosoftAppId, credentials.MicrosoftAppPassword).GetTokenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify where the message is coming from and where you are trying to download the attachment to? Also, can you describe the behavior you're seeing when the bot works correctly?

Comment: The message is coming from Skype (image attachment). I'm trying to download in the bot service and save in local storage.

Comment: Is it an image you're trying to send to the user in the conversation, or are a you trying to save an image sent by the user?